# how to survive from back or home button in an ANDROID APP if I don't want to close my APP

Tags: android

I want to create one app in which it should be a kind of administrator app, where **user not able to close that app by pressing back or home button**, so how to handle these back & home buttons in an Android app.

Comment: what you want to achieve in that app

Comment: just override `onBackPressed(){ }` without doing anything

Comment: I have a set of apps installed in my mobile phone but If any other person wants to access my mobile I will allow him to launch app from my app, so I can control which app can be accessed/not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following method in your Activity to **Disable the back button.**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // nothing to do here
  // … really      
}
```

Disabling **Back** `Button` is a simple one but for **Home** `Button` you need to add more logic.

Check this [link](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) for disabling **Home** `Button`.

Comment: Good to see somebody mention the home button too, instead of simple handling back press. Would you not be able to get around that, by clicking on a push message in your notification bar?

Comment: Yes, @Kevin you are right, so yea how to prevent that one(pressing notification message) ?

Comment: I highly doubt you'd be able to prevent it all together, seems like it could be pretty malicious to prevent an app from closing. So I think use the solution from @uday, but be aware that its never going to be 100%. So handle the case where your app loses the foreground

Answer (score 0):

That's not really recommended but you can override `onBackPressed()` and not calling anything (Including super)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     //Do nothing or at least show the user a toast
}
```

Comment: Is this will work If I want something like child mode where by long pressing home or back button should not close my app. To be frank in any way I don't want to close my app without password or some other tricks.